# How can i configure Ansible and Jenkins if both are not on same machine?

Tags: ansible

I have Jenkins and Ansible Server installed on different window machines .But how to trigger ansible playbook from jenkins
I added Ansible server as a Slave in Jenkins Server . I need solution on how to trigger anisble playbook
from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins >Available > search Ansible. If you are already installed Ansible Plugin on your Jenkins It will display in the Installed section. Now we can see the Invoke Ansible Playbook option in the Build Environment section but we need to configure Ansible path for Jenkins

Comment: how can i configure ansible path as jenkins server and ansible server are on different machines?